# What would be the best way to take a specified input and see if two lists share it?

Tags: c#, list

I have to make an application where you enter a name, and the application looks at two lists. If it matches it tells you. Otherwise it will say it can't find a match. What would the best way to do this?

Comment: `list1.Contains(input) && list2.Contains(intput)` ?

Comment: So you want it to check for variable match in two different lists?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Thank you that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
List<string> firstList ;
List<string> secondList;

// precondition:  firstList and secondList have been populated
protected bool ExistsInBothList(string sInput)
{   
    bool inFirstList = firstList.Any(x => x == sInput);
    bool inSecondList = secondList.Any(x => x == sInput);

    return inFirstList && inSecondList;
}
```

Comment: You can improve by skipping second list check if the first list check fails. Condition1 && Condition2 directly will do.